# How can I show ellipses on my TextView if it is greater than the 1 line?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, textview

I have the following Layout which does not work:

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/experienceLayout" 
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="6dp" 
    android:paddingRight="6dp" 
    android:paddingBottom="6dp" 
    android:paddingTop="6dp">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/experienceLabel" 
        android:text="Experience" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/experienceTextView" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:ellipsize="end" 
        android:lines="1" 
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:fadeScrollbars="false">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 339, accepted):

This is a common problem.  Try using the following:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

.............. the scrollHorizontally is the "special sauce" that makes it work.

Comment: Strange... I tried `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` but it didn't work, I had to use the deprecated attribute `android:singleLine="true"`.

Comment: yes `scrollHorizontally` is the actual key to `...`

Comment: scrollHorizontally? obviously i don't want a horizontal scroll effect.

Comment: @user1232726:  Yes, "scroll horizontally."  As a matter of common sense, take a look at the date of the question and the date of the responses ... goes without saying that neither might be currently relavant (before commenting).

Comment: Using ellipsize with maxLines might crash the app - Report from Android Studio intellisense

Comment: @VaishnavMhetre I just implement the solution above and has no crash at all.

Comment: Works without scrollHorizontally property.

Answer (score 38):

This will also make a single line with ellipsise

```
 android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: This is deprecated apparently

Comment: This one better breaks long words.

Comment: android:maxLines="1"

Comment: @grebulon It is deprecated. At least now.

Answer (score 25):

**Use this**

```
android:ellipsize="end"  
android:singleLine="true"
```

---

**Don't use this without fully aware of what output comes**

```
android:ellipsize="end"  
android:maxLines="1"
```

When you use `maxlines = 1` it will some time truncate most of the characters.

Answer (score 20):

The way it worked for me on multiple devices / APIs was programmatically like this (where tv is your TextView):

```
    if (tv.getLineCount() > 1) {
        int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
        String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "\u2026";
        tv.setText(text);
    }
```

Comment: This is the most helpful answer of all... works on every single API and can be easily convert it as a Utils library.

Comment: You should use the ellipsis character `\u2026` instead of the three `.` characters

Comment: You are right @ChrisStillwell and I do use the ellipsis character in my code. I've edited the answer, thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

So all the answers above cater to the requirement that only 1 line and then the ellipsis should appear. However if you want the ellipsis to appear after certain lines of text, then you should use the following:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="2"
android:singleLine="false"
```

With this the ellipsis will appear only after 2 lines. Note: Its important to have singleLine as false.

Comment: The default value is false according to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:singleLine

Answer (score 3):

This helped me out:

```xml
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Make sure the `TextView` `width` is set to `Match_Parent`

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/43#issuecomment-523701518

Answer (score 2):

`android:singleLine` is deprecated. In my case, I had to get a fixed height for the `TextView` and I used the `android:lines` attribute instead of `android:maxLines`. I thought this might help someone having the same problem as mine.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:lines="2"
```

Comment: Not true. Documentation doesn't say anything about deprecation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: @cesards Interesting. This document says that it is - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine

Comment: @cesards, According to Android in Code documentation:

This (android:singleLine) attribute is deprecated. Use maxLines instead to change the layout of a static text, and use the textMultiLine flag in the inputType attribute instead for editable text views (if both singleLine and inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine).