# How to show long text only show 1 lines and append with 

Tags: android, layout, textview

How to show long text only show 1 lines and append with ....

I try

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle" 
        android:text="testqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:lines="1" 
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#545454"/>
```

but it show some text and doesn't append with ...

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this out ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393487/how-can-i-show-ellipses-on-my-textview-if-it-is-greater-than-the-1-line/6393730#6393730)  Add the scrollHorizontally element also.