# what should i have to do to show three points after text that is to large?

Tags: java, android

I want to do something like picture below
I want to write the text in the Edittext hint and if it can't show full text write three points(...) after it  I'd like it to be in just one line of code.

[it's a edit text hint in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUyne.png)

Comment: check this link http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/ also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597550/ideal-method-to-truncate-a-string-with-ellipsis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show ellipses on my TextView if it is greater than the 1 line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393487/how-can-i-show-ellipses-on-my-textview-if-it-is-greater-than-the-1-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length and if is ***longer than*** , then truncate the text....

```
if (myTextView.length >15){

 myTextView.setText(myTextView.getText().substring(0,10)+"...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following XML attributes on your EditText:

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```